# Checking if a specified position in a string contains a letter or a digit

Tags: java, string, contains

I wish to check whether a string contains a letter or a digit in a specified position.

Here's the problem:

I have a input string of length 2. The string is of the form *"a1"*. 
I'm making a validation method for these types of strings.

Requirements:

- the letter at index position 0 has to be one of the letters: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
- the number/digit at index position 1 has to be one of the numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Thanks!

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: Read the string, check the first char, then check the second char. Done.

Comment: Have you tried [String.charAt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))?

Comment: I tried the charAt() and checked each index position, but couldn't get this to check for all the characters/digits i wanted to check. Also tried to loop through for checking.
Did the regex method now (.matches()) and that worked out perfect.

Answer (score 4):

regex

```
input.matches("^[abcdefgh][12345678]$");
```

Edit:

This is equivalent to:

```
input.matches("^[a-h][1-8]$");
```

- The ^ anchors the match-check to the beginning of the input string.
- The [a-h] says the first character in the string (after the ^) can be one of the characters a through h.
- The [1-8]  says the second character can be 1 through 8.
- The $ indicates that the next thing after the [1-8] *must* be the end of the string.

Comment: I find `^[a-h][1-8]$`much easier

Comment: You can use `"^[a-h][1-8]$"` as pattern, don't have to specify all letters or digits that you should match

Comment: @rolfl do you really want novices to explicitly enumerate every character available? I don't see how that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: extract the n-th letter and check if it is a number or letter:

```
isaletter(mystring.charAt(0));
isanumber(mystring.charAt(1));
```

Flexible answer: use a regex. You will need to learn something about them, but they offer great flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

try regex

```
 str.matches("[a-h][1-8]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a char array, "a1".toCharArray()

Compare char[0] to your fields 'a'....'h' you can use == now that its a primitive, as in chars[0] == 'a'.

You can do the same for chars[1] == '1'....so on.

If you do this, you'll have to compare to the character values.

Answer (score 0):

Is speed, memory, or efficiency important?  Looks like you should make two lists, loop through them (nested), then test if the concatenated list values are ==.  Like ((myList(indexOuter) + my2ndList(indexInner)) == "theListHoldingYourStrings(stringIndex)).  I'm new to Java and don't know what the fastest, efficient methods are however.

Use a 64 member switch statement.

```
switch(stringToTest) {
case "a1":  System.out.println("Valid");
             break;
case "a2": System.out.println("Valid");
             break;
```

.
.
.